# Extract all images from zillow html - to google sheets with Regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Hello i want to extract all images from zillow HTML

https://regex101.com/r/ifKDEa/1

Im trying to catch first 7 images

```
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/4e900eea9506449f780cf1ffe718ff0e-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/209c61592b999d83ca05b9b1e76edb5c-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/1c1fe680263f8ac0ce477a5e82c589c7-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/f6cbaed9371bacf8e259dbb83336f3a2-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/19369ad2675cbb63a580dc204697ab07-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/a59b1aba32afef92744c3a5b17123275-cc_ft_960.jpg   
https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/abd1fea3dcdef3deddaa4a0ebbe84696-cc_ft_960.jpg
```

I want to paste this html in google sheets and extract image links there

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: When I saw your `regex101.com`, I thought that in this case, Google Apps Script might be suitable because your HTML data size might be over 50 kbytes. How about this? For example, can you provide the URL of your HTML data?

Comment: Sure any zillow link, for exemple this one https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/6267-Goddess-Ct-San-Jose-CA-95129/19646000_zpid/?

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the URL. When I check the HTML from the URL, it seems that your expected values are put using Javascript. By this, unfortunately, your expected values cannot be directly retrieved by Google Apps Script and Spreadsheet. In this case, for example, when the HTML data is manually retrieved using a browser and saved the HTML as a file to Google Drive, I think that your expected values can be retrieved using Google Apps Script. How about this workaround?

Comment: Yes i have a way to scrape them in this html format i added to regex, i just dont have options of extracting only those links

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

When I check the HTML from your provided URL, it seems that your expected values are put using Javascript. By this, unfortunately, your expected values cannot be directly retrieved by Google Apps Script and Spreadsheet. In this case, as a workaround for indirectly achieving your goal, when the HTML data is manually retrieved using a browser and saved the HTML as a file to Google Drive, I think that your expected values can be retrieved using Google Apps Script. In this answer, I would like to propose this workaround.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

Before you use this script, please put HTML data as a file to your Google Drive. And, please set the filename to `filename` and run the script. By this, the URLs are retrieved and put on the active sheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const filename = "samplefilename.html";
  const html = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename).next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const urls = [...html.matchAll(/https:\/\/photos\.zillowstatic\.com\/fp\/[\w\d\-_]+?\.jpg/g)];
  if (!urls || urls.length == 0) return;
  
  // console.log(urls) // When you use this, the URLs can be seen at the log.

  // If you want to put the URLs to the active sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, urls.length).setValues(urls);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Unfortunately i have to do this in bulk cannot save manually file by file, i was able to shorten html code and now i can scrape in this format https://regex101.com/r/td3T5I/1 and i want to extract only those with -cc_ft_960.jpg this html will be pasted in spreadsheet

Comment: @petrosaurus Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `i want to extract all images from zillow HTML`, I had thought that you might have wanted to retrieve all jpg images. I couldn't notice `i want to extract only those with -cc_ft_960.jpg`. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. When you want to retrieve the images of `-cc_ft_960.jpg`, please modify the regex to `https:\/\/photos\.zillowstatic\.com\/fp\/[\w\d]+?\-cc_ft_960\.jpg` and test it again.

Comment: No worries, i tried this regex but its only extracting one link not all https://regex101.com/r/7QQYaO/1

Comment: @petrosaurus Thank you for replying. I noticed that your HTML data had been changed from your 1st one. In your new HTML data, it seems that 2 URLs are retrieved. I cannot replicate `i tried this regex but its only extracting one link not all`. I apologize for this.

Comment: To a user who voted. Could you please tell me the modification point in my answer? I would like to study from it.